# How can I create RMarkdown files that render well in PDF and HTML and which also contain numbered figures?

Tags: r, r-markdown, knitr, pandoc, cross-reference

I have been working on some documents that should render in both HTML and PDF.
For referencing in Latex I have used the `\ref{fig:fig1}`style and giving figures a numbered caption.

For referencing in HTML I have tried several other things. Using `bookdown::html_document2` enables me to use `\@ref(fig:fig1)`.

But this is still not the same text. Is there a way of referencing figures that works in both PDF and HTML and uses the same tag in the source Rmd-file?

I've tried using `knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")` to create a function that switches between contexts, but this seems unsatisfactory. Are there any better options?

Thanks :)

I wrote this helper function, but this seems too complex.

```r
ref <- function(label,output = knitr::opts_knit$get("rmarkdown.pandoc.to")){
  if(!is.null(output)){
    if(output == "latex") {
      return(
        paste0("\\ref{",label,"} ")
        )
    }
    if(output == "html") {
      return(paste0("\\@ref(",label,") "))
    }
  }
}
```

## ------------ Solution ---------------

When using both `pdf_document2` and `html_document2` as output from `bookdown`, the regular `\@ref(fig:fig)` version works.

Comment: "But this is still not the same text" <- Could you please elaborate with an example? I have no idea what this means.

Comment: have a look at https://github.com/lierdakil/pandoc-crossref (or roll your own pandoc filter: https://pandoc.org/lua-filters.html)

Comment: @yihui-xie Maybe I am doing something incredible stupid, but I thought that for Latex I would have to write `\ref{fig:fig}` using curly brackets, and for HTML i would have to write `\@ref(fig:fig)` with the @-symbol and regular brackets.

Comment: I meant "Please _edit your post_ and include an example to show us what you did".

Comment: Just added a function that I now use.

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question. I just realized that when I set the PDF output to bookdown::pdf_document2 I can use the HTML version.